# "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property" while sorting by non-PK column

Tags: hibernate, api, sorting, criteria

```
Class A {
 private long id; //PK
 private B b; // FK many-to-one

 public long getId() {
    return this.id;
 }

 public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public B getB() {
    return this.b;
 }

 public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
 }
}

Class B {
 private String code; // PK

 private String name;

 public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
 }

 public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }   
}
```

Retrieving a list of A objects and sorting by b.code or b.name as follows

```
public List<A> loadListOfAs(final Integer id) {
        final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        //criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("b.code")); -- uncommenting this line and deleting the line below works
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("b.name")); // Using this line errors out         
        final List<A> returnList = findByCriteria(criteria); 
        return returnList;
    }
```

Sorting by b.code works but sorting by b.name throws the following
    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: b.name of: A

Answer (score 0):

So here is how the criteria should be to achieve this -

```
public List<A> loadListOfAs(final Integer id) {
final DetachedCriteria c1= DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
DetachedCriteria c2 = c1.createCriteria("b");
c2.addOrder(Order.asc("name")); 

final List<A> returnList = findByCriteria(c1); 
return returnList;
}
```